# Unit test when class has dependency on protected property of base class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, protected, base-class

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
    protected void OnSomeEvent(EventContext context)
    {
         SomeType  = _someService.DoSomeLogic(context);
    }

    public SomeType SomeType { get; private set; } 
}
```

`MyBaseClass` works some magic to initialise a public property value when an event is triggerd in the process pipline.

```
public class MyClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public string Foo()
    {
        if (SomeType.SomeLogic())
            throw new InvalidOpertaionException();

        return "huzzah";
    }
}
```

The flow in other classes depends on `SomeType` being initialised.

How can I unit test `MyClass.Foo()`?

```
[TestMethod]
public void Foo_ReturnsHuzzah()
{
    var result = new MyClass().Foo(); 
    Assert.IsHuzzah(result);   
}
```

Comment: I assume SomeType is not supposed to have that public setter.

Comment: @Sign ah yes good spot. setter should be private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of temporal coupling (the event must be raised before the call to `Foo` is valid) is often considered a design flaw so the first thing I would do is revisit the design to make sure what I have is right.

If you don't want to go that route, the easiest solution is to initialize `SomeType` with a Null Object implementation of `SomeType` like so...

```
class NullSomeType : SomeType
{
    public override bool SomeLogic() { return false; }
}
```

Then you default SomeType with the Null Object in the constructor.

```
public MyBaseClass()
{
   SomeType = new NullSomeType();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

_someService looks like an external dependency. I would use Dependency Injection to make that external dependency injectable, and then use a mocking framework to inject something that returns state that will make the rest of your tests pass.

Then run the public method that ultimately invokes OnSomeEvent, and you can test the whole chain of processing

Comment: I am DIing `_someService`. The problem is I can't invoke `OnSomeEvent` - it is invoked by the ASP.NET pipeline but I have no idea when/how.

Answer (score 0):

Set `SomeType` before calling `Foo()`

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the question, `SomeType` has no public setter.